# Android Studio: TextView in Second Activity not Updating

Tags: java, android, android-activity, textview, updating

I am trying to change the text of a `TextView` at runtime when the user taps a button. I call `setText()` from a private method in a Fragment which should update a `TextView` in an XML used by an `Activity` I have created. The Fragment is one of those generated by the Navigation Drawer Activity preset in case that's helpful.
Here is the method inside the Fragment:

```
private void openGameActivity(List<Game> currentYearCategory, int gameNum){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_game, null, false);

        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.refereeAndDate);

        String string = "test string";
        textView.setText(string);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GameActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The activity opens correctly and there are no errors. `findViewById` is able to find the `TextView` and calling `setText()` must change the text because I have tried calling `getText()` on the `TextView` and it returns the updated value. The problem is that when I run the app the `TextView` text doesn't visually update. This is the activity code in case it is useful:

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setSubtitle(R.string.page_game_details);
        }
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        finish();
        return true;
    }
}
```

The `TextView` XML code from the `activity_game` layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/refereeAndDate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="The match was refereed by Brown on 16/04/12." />
```

I am sure that the ID of this `TextView` is not a duplicate. How to make it update?

Comment: so you want to update text from a fragment to activity ?

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass `String` from `Fragment` to `Activity` using `Intent` like below:

```
private void openGameActivity(List<Game> currentYearCategory, int gameNum){
    ....

    String string = "test string";
    textView.setText(string);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GameActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("SHARED_CONTENT", string);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then in your `GameActivity` change like below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ....

    TextView refereeAndDate = findViewById(R.id.refereeAndDate);
    String string = getIntent().getStringExtra("SHARED_CONTENT");
    refereeAndDate.setText(string);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Cameron, did you check that?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm away right now but I will check when I get back tomorrow!

Comment: Yep @Md. Asaduzzaman that worked perfectly! Thanks for the help and quick reply! :)